# tfs problem. Cannot open solution file

Tags: vb.net, tfs, projects-and-solutions

i have this project in TFS, and someone else from another computer changed the solution file's name. Now when i try to open it, i cant. It gives ne this error -
"This project (xxx.sln) cannot be opened from source control because it was created by a version of Microsoft Visual Studio that is incompatible with this one.
If this is the case, you may be able to open it from source control using that version of Microsoft Visual Studio, and then use Microsoft Visual Studio to open the local copy."

I dont have a local copy cause i deleted it. Reason being i wanted to get eveything new from the server. How can i open this project now?

Comment: is your problem solved? Do you need more information?

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the project in Source Control explorer, choose 'get specific version'
In the dialog that opens, choose latest version' and check the box that says you want to overwrite the local file even if your workspace already has the latest version.

That way, you'll have the file you deleted on your local disk again.

If you still can't open it in visual studio, open the file in notepad and see if the version of the file matches up with your version of visual studio

That should look something like this:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
```

10.00 = VS2008
11.00 = VS2010

If it doesn't match your version of VS, it was opened in another version of VS and converted.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Visual Studio
2. Open Source Control Explorer (View -> Other Windows -> SOurce Control)
3. Right click on the folder in Source Control where you solution is
4. Start the Get latest command

You now have the latest version of you solution file and you can open it again

Comment: If he previously deleted the file, he has to use 'get specific version' and check "force get even if the file already exists in the workspace"